# Вибрация на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, mobile

Здравствуйте хочу сделать вибрацию на мобильных устройствах и везде больше всего рекомендуют:https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vibrate. Мне этот вариант тоже нравится, но кроссбраузерность нулевая, не поддерживает даже Яндекс. Подскажите знаете ли более адаптивный способ?

Comment: Других способов не существует

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, возможно вы знаете какой-либо 'хак' для большей поддержки?

Comment: Можете ответить, я проголосую за него и отмечу